# Variable undefined when i'ts from 2 different function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to add the 2 variable that are in 2 different function. But it's giving an undefined result. the n_standard and n_quad is initialized

```
var n_standard = 0;
var n_quad = 0;
var totalQuad = quadRoom();
var totalStandard = standardRoom();
var total = totalStandard + totalQuad;

function standardRoom() {

  n_standard = n_standard + Number($("#selectBoxStandard").val());

  var totalStandard = {{$availableRooms[0]['nightRate'] * $n_nights }} * n_standard;


      $("#totals ul").html('<li>Total:'+ total +'</li>');
      return totalStandard;

}

  function quadRoom()
{
    n_quad = n_quad + Number($("#selectBoxQuad").val());

   var totalQuad = {{$availableRooms[1]['nightRate'] * $n_nights}} * n_quad;

   return totalQuad;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring them twice. remove `var` in the functions. Declaring them in the top scope makes them available everywhere.

Also, the functions quadRoom and standardRoom aren't available to those variables as they're only defined once the line they're on is reached.

You can try declaring the functions as variables with arrow functions.
In general...

var x = (a, b) => {return a * b};

In your case..

```
var totalQuad;
 var quadRoom = () => {
  n_quad = n_quad + Number($("#selectBoxQuad").val());
  totalQuad = {{$availableRooms[1]['nightRate'] * $n_nights}} * n_quad;

return totalQuad;
}
```

Comment: We're talking about `totalQuad` and `totalStandard`, right?

Comment: The `total` is the one that is undefined. Sorry for the confusion. The `totalQuad` and `totalStandard` should be added.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Can you give me a sample?

Comment: I'ts still not working, do I do that to both quadRoom and standardRoom? Even if I do both, the total is NaN